# How to find $\int \frac {\sec x}{1+ \csc x} dx $?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

> How to find $\int \frac {\sec x}{1+ \csc x} dx  $ ?

Well it reduces to $ \int \frac {\sin x}{\cos x (1+\sin x)} dx $ .Any hints next ?

I'm looking for a short and simple method without partial fractions if possibe.

Comment: Why not convert everything to tan by half angle formulae and then $tan(x/2)=t$

Comment: That would make it more complicated...

Comment: I got the answer as $sec^3(x)/5tan(x)-sec^2(x)-tan^2(x)/2-2ln|sec(x)|+C$

Comment: Would you mind to tell the final answer

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$ \int \frac {\sin x}{\cos x (1+\sin x)} dx =\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x(1+\sin x)}dx=\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{(1-\sin^2 x)(1+\sin x)}dx\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2(1-\sin x)}dx$$

Take $u=\sin x$ and use partial fractions.

Comment: OP mentioned that he didnt want to use partial fractions

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Anyway, he said "if possible", and this method isn't all that complicated.

Comment: This is much simpler than using the tangent half-angle substitution, for sure.

Comment: I thought using $secx=√1+tan^2x$…and same thing for cosecx and then rationalizing and integrating

Answer (score 2):

First, we write
$$
\frac{\sec x}{1+\csc x}=\frac{\tan x}{1+\sin x}=\frac{\tan x(1-\sin x)}{1-\sin^2x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\tan x-\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan^2 x.
$$
Now
$$
\int\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\tan x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\tan^2x.
$$
For the other part we integrate by parts,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan^2x\,dx&=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}\tan x\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan x-\int\frac{1}{\cos x}(1+\tan^2x)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan x-\int\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2x}\,dx-\int\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan^2x\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan x-\text{artanh}\,\sin x-\int\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan^2x\,dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now it is a matter of rearranging. I get the final result to be something like

> $$ \int\frac{\sec x}{1+\csc x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\text{artanh}\,(\sin x)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\cos x}\tan x+\frac{1}{2}\tan^2x+C.$$